# Can you use Ingress equipment at a lower level?

Tags: ingress

When I was Level 2, I had acquired quite a few Level 3 bursters and things. I would have liked to have used them, even if they'd been treated as only Level 2 items. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: While you are not level 5 or 6, don't try to fight. Just hack, build, link, field. Your task now is to get lvl8 as soon as possible. It could be done in couple of days, if you are living in big city.

Comment: Resonators are the main ingredient of the "and things" part of this question. So it's not just about fighting.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is rather short: No -- unless you regard recycling them for their XM as "using".

Comment: For Power Cube, it is the case. For bursters and resonators, just keep them, there will be useful when levelling up.

Comment: You don't get higher-level cubes when hacking, so the question doesn't apply to them.

Comment: @MatthiasUrlichs you can pick them up from the ground if someone drops them, even at level 1.

Comment: @simbabque can those higher-level cubes then be recycled for full value?

Comment: @mm yes that is possible it seems. At level 3 you can recycle a pc6 for 6000, but you only have an XM pool of 5000 available.